# Fetch values from nested xml (having : in tag name) in php

Tags: php, xml, drupal

I have xml like this

```
<item>
    <title>test title</title>
    <link>www.test.com</link>
    <pubDate>Sun, 27 Aug 2017 06:22:29 +0000</pubDate>
    <post-id xmlns="com-wordpress:feed-additions:1">1111</post-id>
    <ev:tribe_event_meta xmlns:ev="Event">
        <ev:startdate>November 13, 2017</ev:startdate>
        <ev:enddate>November 14, 2017</ev:enddate>
        <ev:venue>venue</ev:venue>
        <ev:address>address</ev:address>
        <ev:city>city</ev:city>
        <ev:zip></ev:zip>
    </ev:tribe_event_meta>
</item>
```

Form this xml i am able to get `title`, `link` etc...

But im not able to get any data inside `ev:tribe_event_meta`. I need to get the value of `ev:startdate`, `ev:enddate`,etc.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

**Note:** I'm using `Drupal Feed Import`.

Comment: The `ev:` prefix is known as a "namespace". Read the documentation to learn how to work with namespaces.

Comment: Did you try the XML Xpath parser from the feeds_ex module ?

Answer (score 0):

XML is just a text file. If your parser can't parse it like that try just doing search/replace on file before passing the file content to the parser. I.e. replace every "ev:startdate" with "ev_startdate" or something.