# Fetch values from nested xml in drupal feed import

Tags: php, xml, import, drupal-7, feed

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <rss version="2.0"
     xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
     xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
     xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
     xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
     xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
     xmlns:ev="http://purl.org/rss/2.0/modules/event/">
     <channel>
        <title>Official Website</title>
        <description>My Vision is a Stress-Free, Violence-Free World </description>
        <lastBuildDate>Tue, 14 Nov 2017 08:03:48 +0000</lastBuildDate>
        <language>en-US </language>
        <site xmlns="com-wordpress:feed-additions:1">114467343</site>
        <item>
           <title>title</title>
           <link>
           https://www.test.org/</link>
           <pubDate>Sun, 27 Aug 2017 06:22:29 +0000</pubDate>
           <dc:creator>
              <![CDATA[atreya]]>
           </dc:creator>
           <post-id xmlns="com-wordpress:feed-additions:1">111</post-id>
           <ev:tribe_event_meta xmlns:ev="Event">
              <ev:startdate>November 13, 2017</ev:startdate>
              <ev:enddate>November 14, 2017</ev:enddate>
              <ev:venue>venue</ev:venue>
              <ev:address>address</ev:address>
              <ev:city>New Delhi</ev:city>
              <ev:stateprovince></ev:stateprovince>
              <ev:country>India</ev:country>
              <ev:zip></ev:zip>
           </ev:tribe_event_meta>
        </item>
     </channel>
  </rss>
```

Form this xml i am able to get `title`, `link` etc...
But im not able to get any data inside `ev:tribe_event_meta`. I need to get the value of `ev:startdate`,`ev:enddate`,etc.
If i remove `xmlns:ev="http://purl.org/rss/2.0/modules/event/` its working

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

**Note**  I'm using `Drupal Feed Import` Module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - how do I handle namespaces (tags and attributes with colon in) in SimpleXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-colon-in-in-si)

Comment: duplicate of 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47279722/fetch-values-from-nested-xml-having-in-tag-name-in-php